# Pipe stdout to loggly via simple bash script

Tags: bash, pipe, stdout, loggly

I want to log stdout from some programs to loggly.  There are a few simple utilities out there that I've found (e.g. https://github.com/meatballhat/loggly-pipe and https://github.com/segmentio/loggly-cat), but they seem like they're overkill.

Could I get away with doing something this simple:

`log.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
    echo "$line"
    curl -H "content-type:text/plain" -d "$line" https://logs-01.loggly.com/inputs/<my-token>/tag/tag1,tag2/ >/dev/null 2>&1
done < /dev/stdin
```

Then I run my program and pipe it to my loggly logging script:

```
./my_script.sh | ./log.sh
```

This seems to work okay, but I wonder if all the complicated-ness of the other solutions out there is necessary for some reason?

Could anything go wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: The `< /dev/stdin` part is unnecessary, by the way.

Comment: Excellent.  Less code more better.

Answer (score 1):

Think about what your script does.  It runs `curl` *once per line of input.*

Think about what that means.

If you log 10K lines, you'll then spawn 10K processes.  Which will initiate 10K TCP connections.  This is a massive waste of computing resources.

Also, you don't handle errors at all (in fact, you actively hide them by sending curl's stderr to /dev/null!).  This means the script is not only inefficient, it is unreliable.

I recommend starting all Bash scripts with `set -eu` to exit on unhandled errors, but that's just one step, not a complete fix for the above.

Comment: So, perhaps batching TCP connections would be less of a waste, and I assume the other solutions do that to some extent.  

I don't necessarily want to handle errors, I just want it to not break or barf if it's not working for any reason.  I'd rather not get logs than break something else.

If I exit with set -eu, would the first my_script.sh continue running?

Comment: No, if the second script in the pipeline stops, the first one will receive SIGPIPE which will in all likelihood stop it also.  It might be a good idea to write the failed log lines to a file or something.